# Why doesn't my QDeclarativeItem get any mouse/keyboard events?

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qml

This is a reduced down, minimum complete example demonstrating my problem:

I have an application which hosts a `QDeclarativeView`; file `events.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include "TestItem.h"

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc,argv);

  qmlRegisterType<TestItem>("Testing",1,0,"Tester");

  QDeclarativeView page;
  page.setSource(QUrl("page.qml"));
  Q_ASSERT(page.status()==QDeclarativeView::Ready);
  page.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

That `TestItem` is a subclassed `QDeclarativeItem` defined in file `TestItem.h`:

```
#ifndef _TestItem_h_
#define _TestItem_h_

#include <iostream>
#include <QDeclarativeItem>
#include <QPainter>

class TestItem : public QDeclarativeItem {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  TestItem() {
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemHasNoContents,false);
    std::cerr << "[TestItem created]";
  }
  void paint(QPainter* painter,const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*,QWidget*) {
    painter->drawLine(0,0,width(),height());
    painter->drawLine(0,height(),width(),0);
  }
protected:
  void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*) {
    std::cerr << "[TestItem::mousePressEvent]";
  }
  void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*) {
    std::cerr << "[TestItem::keyPressEvent]";
  }
};

#endif
```

and the `page.qml` file loaded into the `QDeclarativeView` is simply:

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import Testing 1.0

Tester {
  width: 200
  height: 200
}
```

It's all built (with Qt 4.8 on Debian-Wheezy amd64) with qmake file

```
CONFIG += debug

QT += core gui declarative

TARGET = events
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += events.cpp 
HEADERS += TestItem.h
```

and, once built, when I run `./events` I get a window displaying the Tester's painted 'X', as expected:

[image]

and a `[TestItem created]` logged to the console.  However, clicking within the window or pressing keys completely fails to invoke either of the mouse or key event handlers.

I'm completely mystified.  Is some extra magic (in the C++ or QML domains) needed to get mouse/keyboard events routed to these sort of "plugin" `QDeclarativeItem` classes?  I certainly don't have any problems defining a `MouseArea` in the QML file and having it do stuff to QML state, and the code this is reduced from has no problems with signals and slots interoperating between the C++ item and QML code... but when it comes to mouse/keyboard events, there's just no sign of them on the C++ side.

Comment: Maybe some connection with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321902/event-providing-to-qwidgetqwt-embedded-into-qml-qt4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get (left) mouse events, all that is needed is to add

```
setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
```

in the `TestItem` constructor.  This is a little surprising as the documentation for the inherited `QGraphicsItem::setAcceptedMouseButtons` says "By default, all mouse buttons are accepted", but maybe something else in the setup messes with the state.

To get keyboard events, `setFocus(true)` just needs to be invoked.  The documentation seems to imply `setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable,true)` should also be called, but it doesn't actually seem to be necessary in my test.